# Winforms cross-thread databinding using BindingList(Of T) in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms, list, data-binding

1. I have a ListBox on my main GUI form (lstDevices).
2. It is bound to a BindingList(of Devices) [AvailableDevices] that is a property of a class [NetworkManager].
3. This BindingList is updated (adds/deletes) inside the Network manager class, triggered by a different thread than the form UI.
4. Every time it (the BindingList) is updated a cross-thread error is thrown and the UI based listbox never updates.

   Form Pseudo Code:

   Dim WithEvents disc As New UPnPDeviceManager.NetworkManager

   lstDevices.DataSource = disc.AvailableDevices

   lstDevices.DisplayMember = "FriendlyName"

H-E-L-P

Comment: `BindingList` is not thread-safe.  You can only touch it on the UI thread.

Comment: What could I use that will fire a notify event (thread safe). I tried list(of type) - but that didn't work..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code to modify the `BindingList` is in a form then you can use that form's `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` method to marshal a call to the UI thread and modify the `BindingList` there.  If the code to modify the `BindingList` is in a non-UI class, which your question suggests is the case, then you should use the `SynchronizationContext` class inside your class to make the modification to the list thread-safe, e.g.

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class SomeClass

    Private threadingContext As SynchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current

    Private Sub DoSomething()
        Dim data As Object

        '...

        'Execute DoSomethingElse on the same thread that the current object was created on.
        Me.threadingContext.Post(AddressOf DoSomethingElse, data)

        '...
    End Sub

    Private Sub DoSomethingElse(data As Object)
        'Cast data parameter as appropriate type and use here.
    End Sub

End Class
```

As long as you create an instance of that class on the UI thread, `DoSomethingElse` will always be executed on the UI thread, regardless of what thread `DoSomething` is executed on.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `BeginInvoke()` to make all changes to the BindingList on the UI thread.